Anydesk does not work after installing VPN
I have a Ubuntu on a PC which i use as a server. The problems started after i installed a vpn on it. After i conntected to a vpn server i lost connection via Anydesk. I only used Anydesk to connect to the server and ran it headlessly. I tried to restart the server to regain anydesk connection but nothing worked and anydesk showed it as "offline". So i tried to connect a monitor to the server with a HDMI and a VGA cable. Only the VGA cable worked (both ports are on the gpu) but when i start the computer i see the whole bootup process and even the ubuntu loading screen and after that is just goes black. I tried multiple options i found on forums and ai offered me. Nothing worked: grub menu nomodeset, recovery mode, and cant even open TTY terminal.
Update:
I booted into Recovery mode and opened the root shell in order to uninstall graphics drivers:
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
After that i tried to
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
And
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
But it said that there are no available drivers for me to install. So i restarted the computer and regained connection via Anydesk. But on monitor it's still just a black screen.

Anydesk and all programs like it do not work over most VPN s. You did not say what kind of VPN. Is it something commercial like ExpressVPN?

Providing specifics are always helpful. What Ubuntu product & release are you using & asking about, eg. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server? a Ubuntu Core 20 Server? or what?  What changes did you make before the problem occurred?

Its running on the latest Ubuntu Desktop version so 24.04.01 i havent used it for a while but started using it again a couple days ago and thats when i updated everything to the latest version. I haven't made any changes although it's been a while since i tried to plug a monitor into it i mostly used it with Anydesk and everything worked without a problem even after restarting the computer anydesk loaded up automatically until this whole VPN situation.

There is a possibility that the VPN setup may have affected your network settings, resulting in anydesk not being able to connect. Due to the occurrence of the display issue, you might also want to try booting in safe graphics mode with nomodeset in GRUB. Try disabling the VPN to see if it's blocking your local network access. If that helps, you can reconnect to the server using SSH to troubleshoot further.

Tried to boot with nomodeset, still black screen. And i am unable to ssh into it. But about the VPN, i used Mullvad VPN and if im correct by default it doesnt connect to a vpn server automatically after boot. And it also shouldn't even start automatically.

Talk to the VPN company.

From AnyDesk s own site.
The AnyDesk VPN creates a private network between local connecting and remote clients. It is not possible to access devices on the remote client's local network or vice versa.
AnyDesk is a VPN. You can not run a VPN over a VPN.
So you can see the startup fine but as soon as the VPN loads the connection is dropped.

Please remove the swearing from the comment.

Yes, at the time i dont know what i was thinking i just connected and in a second or so i realised i made a mistake, thats why i went to restart the computer. But i dont think just because i connected to a vpn server it would start and connect automatically on boot preventing me to connect to it with Anydesk. But i am not sure the VPN situation is relating to the black screen problem after plugging in a monitor.

hi when active your vpn , go to system proxy system and copy your http proxy address and port and then go to anydesk settings , first of all in VPN section deactive the default vpn address and second , go to connection section and active the "use specific proxy " option and paste your vpn proxy address and port there.
